# Why does mean crease not work properly?

Tags: modeling

So I want the back of the ship's mesh to be pulled to the mean crease (1) I have set. When I try to fix it, I am left with an ugly result.

[image]

Comment: I fear the question is not particularly clear...can you elaborate a bit more, maybe show some reference image of what you wish to achieve?

Comment: try removing duplicite vertices

Answer (score -1):

Give **those** edges some fun ;) (understand *Mean Crease*):

[image]

(also the bottom ones respectively)